# Unknown arg `moderatedBy` in data.moderatedBy for type UserUncheckedUpdateInput

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, prisma

I am getting this error when I try to update a users `moderatedBy` relation (many-to-many self relation) with a `connectOrCreate`. I don't know why there is no `moderatedBy` field on the `UserUncheckedUpdateInput` (prisma generate command doesn't change that).

Error:

```
Unknown arg `moderatedBy` in data.moderatedBy for type UserUncheckedUpdateInput. Available args:

type UserUncheckedUpdateInput {
  id?: String | StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  login?: String | StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  display_name?: String | StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  type?: String | StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  broadcaster_type?: String | StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  description?: String | StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  profile_image_url?: String | StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  offline_image_url?: String | StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  view_count?: Int | IntFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  email?: String | StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  created_at?: DateTime | DateTimeFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  provider?: String | StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  accessToken?: String | StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  refreshToken?: String | StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  updatedAt?: DateTime | DateTimeFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  createdEvents?: EventUncheckedUpdateManyWithoutAuthorInput
  hostedEvents?: EventUncheckedUpdateManyWithoutHostInput
}
```

Query:

```
  const updateUser = await prisma.user.update({
    where: { id: userObj.id },
    data: {
      moderatedBy: {
        connectOrCreate: {
          where: { id: newModerator.user_id },
          create: {
              id: newModerator.user_id,
              login: newModerator.user_login,
              display_name: newModerator.user_name,
              type: '',
              broadcaster_type: '',
              description: '',
              profile_image_url: '',
              offline_image_url: '', 
              view_count: 0,
              email: '',
              created_at: '',
              provider: '',
              accessToken: '',
              refreshToken: ''
          }
        },
      },
    },
  })
```

Schema:

```
model User {
  id                String @id
  login             String
  display_name      String
  type              String
  broadcaster_type  String
  description       String
  profile_image_url String
  offline_image_url String
  view_count        Int
  email             String
  created_at        DateTime
  provider          String

  accessToken       String
  refreshToken      String
  
  updatedAt         DateTime @updatedAt

  createdEvents     Event[]  @relation("Author")
  hostedEvents      Event[]  @relation("Host")

  moderatedBy       User[]   @relation("UserModerate", references: [id])
  moderating        User[]   @relation("UserModerate", references: [id])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your query must change to:

```
 const updateUser = await prisma.user.update({
 where: { id: userObj.id },
 data: {
  id: newModerator.user_id,
  login: newModerator.user_login,
  display_name: newModerator.user_name,
  type: "",
  broadcaster_type: "",
  description: "",
  profile_image_url: "",
  offline_image_url: "",
  view_count: 0,
  email: "",
  created_at: "",
  provider: "",
  accessToken: "",
  refreshToken: "",
  updatedAt:"",
   },
});
```